# I want to draw an animation on the canvas, do I have to use many different pictures or can it be saved like a real animation (.gif maybe) in one file?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

For my game I need to animate the walking of a character/npc. I used to have many different *.png* images for every move, but can I put it all in one file? I'd like to avoid using *.gif*, because I need transparent background, so a *.png* file would be preferred. This isn't really crucial, but will just save me some time, and coding...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use one image to show several character animation states.

It works by creating a long image containing your states, and then placing it on the canvas so that only one state shows at a time.  This should work for any image type that would be supported by the browser.

This game tutorial explains it: http://michalbe.blogspot.com/2010/09/simple-game-with-html5-canvas-part-2.html

Comment: Thank you very much! Although I think it will be simpler just to shuffle different images, I will see.